# Magento 2.4 : Admin Custom page block not loading

Tags: magento2.4

I have created a custom backend page and need to show some custom content within the page. For that I have created

**1. Controller/Adminhtml/Sync/Index.php**
Here in this, getBlock() `$block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('odoo.sync');` returns a false value and, output rendered with neither default backend layout nor mentioned custom block. A plain page without backend layout is loaded.

```
<?php
namespace Iwdat\StockManager235\Controller\Adminhtml\Sync;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku; 
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory;        
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{

    protected $resultPageFactory = false;  
    protected $indexerInterfaceFactory;
    protected $indexerRegistry; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,        
        LoggerInterface $logger,            
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Product $product,    
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku,
        StockRegistryInterface $StockRegistryInterface,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        SourceItemInterfaceFactory $sourceItemFactory,
        SourceItemsSaveInterface $sourceItemsSaveInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl, 
        IndexerInterfaceFactory $indexerInterfaceFactory,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
    ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            .
            .
            .
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //$collection->setPageSize(10); // fetching only 10 products

        return $collection;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend('Odoo Sync');
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('odoo.sync');

        .
        .
        .

        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

**2. view/adminhtml/layout/odoo_sync.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="odoo.sync" template="Iwdat_StockManager235::odoo_sync.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**3. view/adminhtml/templates/odoo_sync.phpml**

```
<h2>Template Here </h2>
```

Can someone please guide me on what changes I should do get the block loaded in to custom backend page.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems correct in your code try adding **cacheable="false"** in your XML file if it is a cache issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="odoo.sync" template="Iwdat_StockManager235::odoo_sync.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```